# Using the DISTINCT keyword causes this error: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT share.rooms
FROM Shares share
  left join share.rooms.buildingAdditions.buildings.buildingInfoses as bi
... //where clause omitted
ORDER BY share.rooms.floors.floorOrder, share.rooms.roomNumber,
         share.rooms.firstEffectiveAt, share.shareNumber, share.sharePercent
```

Which results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

If I remove the DISTINCT keyword, the query runs without issue.  If I remove the order by clause, the query runs without issue.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the ordered result set without duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @Lamak for the response.  It isn't clear to me why the DISTINCT causes the db to ignore the other columns, as it doesn't ignore them without the DISTINCT.  However, given that it matters, how do I get the ordered, duplicate free result set?

Comment: then how do you want them to be ordered?. If you want duplicate free results for the column `share.rooms`, then you need to understand that since the same room **may** have different values for `floorOrder` or `roomNumber` or any other column, how do you want them to be ordered?, by the min value of those?, the max?.

Comment: As a side note: I come here because of a similar issue, happened I forgot an id column (I used for debugging) in the order by clause

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You are trying to order your result with columns that are not being calculated. This wouldn't be a problem if you didn't have the `DISTINCT` there, but since your query is basically grouping only by `share.rooms` column, how can it order that result set with other columns that can have multiple values for the same  `share.rooms` one?

Comment: Interesting that this error is not detected at compile time, but only at runtime.

Comment: @david-balažic: It's because the query isn't compiled. It is sent to the Oracle server at runtime and only then parsed and executed.

Comment: @D.Mika I was referring to usage in a PL/SQL code, which is compiled ahead of execution.

Comment: @DavidBalažic ah ok. In that case you are right. This could be detected at compile time.

Comment: It can be ordered but Oracle refuses to do because the order can be hidden, it works as is in another DBMS. What I hate about it is how Oracle error messages are misleading/obfuscating

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I wanted to add my 2 cents here.  I got the same error when I mistakenly changed a NVL value in the select but did not change it in the order by.  Oops...

Answer (score 9):

This post is a little old but one thing I did to get around this error is wrap the query and just apply the order by on the outside like so.

```
SELECT COL
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT COL, ORDER_BY_COL
   FROM TABLE
   // ADD JOINS, WHERE CLAUSES, ETC.
) 
ORDER BY ORDER_BY_COL;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: wouldn't that select the distinct from both values?

Comment: @Enerccio Yes, you're correct. https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-basics/db2-select-distinct/#:~:text=The%20DISTINCT%20keyword%20is%20applied,use%20the%20GROUP%20BY%20clause.

Comment: @MatthewZackschewski so what is the correct solution? Because if two rows have different column B and you only want column A to be distinct but order by B you are screwed because you get duplicit As in result...

Comment: @Enerccio I can't find a good SQL way to dedup and preserve order. I see many references for doing that but only within one table. Once you start joining, it becomes much more difficult. I would recommend that you implement logic within whatever program is leveraging this and use a hashmap or some other efficient memory structure to dedup on that end. Sorry for the less than optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

When using `DISTINCT` in a query that has an `ORDER BY` you must select all the columns you've used in the `ORDER BY` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT share.rooms.floors.floorOrder, share.rooms.roomNumber,
         share.rooms.firstEffectiveAt, share.shareNumber, share.sharePercent
...
ORDER BY share.rooms.floors.floorOrder, share.rooms.roomNumber,
         share.rooms.firstEffectiveAt, share.shareNumber, share.sharePercent
```