# ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to fetch details from DB. Any thing wrong in my code?

```
SELECT DISTINCT FNAME, LNAME, MEMBERORG, DAYCOUNT, TIMESTAMP, COUNT(FNAME) AS total,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE) AS tot
FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE 
WHERE ID = '68' AND TYPE = 'node'
GROUP BY FNAME, LNAME, MEMBERORG, DAYCOUNT, TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
```

This giving me an error:

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 10
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the DISTINCT keyword causes this error: not a SELECTed expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275447/using-the-distinct-keyword-causes-this-error-not-a-selected-expression)

Comment: I removed distinct from query. But now the error is `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 10`

Comment: The new error tells you that you're trying to `order by` a column `title` that you're not selecting.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The problem here is the `ORDER BY` column `TITLE` isn't selected in the `DISTINCT` query. Since `DISTINCT` is used, the `SELECT` query will try to group the `resultset` based on the selected columns.

`ORDER BY` column isn't selected here, it doesn't ensure the uniqueness on the `resultset` and hence it fails to apply `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `title` column to your `SELECT` statement. When you're using `DISTINCT`, you must have all the columns from the `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement as well.

```
-- correct
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM tbl.x ORDER BY a,b;

-- incorrect
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM tbl.x ORDER BY a,b;
```

The `a` and `b` columns must be selected.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FNAME, LNAME, MEMBERORG, DAYCOUNT, TIMESTAMP, total, tot
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT FNAME, LNAME, MEMBERORG, DAYCOUNT, TIMESTAMP, COUNT(FNAME) AS total,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE) AS tot
FROM REPORT_VIEW_PAGE 
WHERE ID = '68' AND TYPE = 'node'
GROUP BY FNAME, LNAME, MEMBERORG, DAYCOUNT, TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY TITLE ASC
)
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation on what you did, and how it solves the problem of the OP?