# ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the next query - o_ski_packages is an object

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT p.resortsn
> BULK   COLLECT INTO v_resortsn_tbl
> FROM   TABLE (o_ski_packages) p;
> ORDER BY p.resort_country_name ASC;
> ```

the result I want is this -

```
resortsn  resort_country_name  
1              AD
2              BU
```

I need distinct since I can have number of records that are the same -

```
1              AD,
1              AD
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the DISTINCT keyword causes this error: not a SELECTed expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275447/using-the-distinct-keyword-causes-this-error-not-a-selected-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `distinct`, the `order by` needs to refer to expressions that are in the `select`.  Otherwise, how would Oracle know which values to choose?

A simple method around that is to use `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
SELECT p.resortsn
BULK COLLECT INTO v_resortsn_tbl
FROM TABLE (o_ski_packages) p
GROUP BY p.resortsn
ORDER BY MAX(p.resort_country_name) ASC;
```

This fixes the problem with your original query, but it only returns one column.  It would seem that you want something like this:

```
SELECT p.resortsn, MAX(p.resort_country_name) as resort_country_name
BULK COLLECT INTO v_resortsn_tbl
FROM TABLE (o_ski_packages) p
GROUP BY p.resortsn
ORDER BY MAX(p.resort_country_name) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I assume, this should work fine as per your requirement, assuming that the query you gave above work fine on its own.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.resortsn, max(resort_country_name) cn
BULK   COLLECT INTO v_resortsn_tbl
FROM   TABLE (O_SKI_PACKAGES) P
group by  p.resortsn
ORDER BY cn ASC;
```

Even though `resort_country_name` is same for your `distinct` resortsn, the DB will never know that. So put `resort_country_name` in any aggregate function which don't need a group by like `MAX`. Also you need to group by resortsn, which might not be necessary if you were selecting just `resortsn`, but as you are using more than one different aggregate functions, you need to group by at least 1. Hence `group by resortsn`

Comment: You don't need `distinct` **and** `group by`. But this is probably not going to work as you are now selecting two columns. It depends on the definition of `v_resortsn_tbl` if the `bulk collect into` is going to work with that

Comment: Agree on that. But without sample data, I just piled on the OP's existing query which, I assume, is using distinct due to some reason. Anyways this will work for any `resortsn` , `resort_country_name` combination. Thanks for pointing it out.